# How to rename/move a file and retain the middle of the filename? I'm using wildcards to find file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to rename the file `process_12345678.pdf` to `process_12345678_0219.pdf`.

I'm adding the month/year before the file extension, and this is what I've been trying.

```
mv process_*{,_$(date +%m%y)}.pdf
```

This changes the file name to `process_*_0219.pdf`

The number in the middle, 12345678, changes every time the process is run. I can't remember or find how to retain the process number.

Comment: I'm surprised it does anything at all ... `mv` usually requires two or more parameters.   And why (how?) did you disable the globbing for `*`?

Comment: You might want to read your `rename` man page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in process_*.pdf
do
    mv "$file" "${file%.pdf}_$(date +%m%y).pdf"
done
```

see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html